# network programming - send file from webserver to client

Tags: php, network-programming

I wrote a php script to upload files to a webserver. There I am able to download it as well. I want to shift the files from the server to a client, so everytime a file is uploaded, it gets pushed to the client as well. Is it even possible to handle that with php scripts, where do I define these operations besides the php scripts, or can it be integrated?

My php scripts for index and upload file:

index:

```
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM documents";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Documents</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <nav id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="upload.php">Upload</a></li>
            <li><a href="downloadlist.php">Download</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>         
</body>
</html>
```

upload:

```
 <?php
    include("db.php");

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];

        if($name){

            $location = "/storage/ssd2/932/2536932/uploads/$name";
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location);
            $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO documents (name, path) VALUES('$name', '$location')");
            header('Location: index.php');
        }
        else 
            die("Please select a file.");       
    }   
    ?>

    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload File</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>Browse File:</label>

            <input type="file" name="myfile">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" onclick="index.php">
        </form>    
    </body>    
    </html>
```

Comment: If the client just uploaded the file, why do you need to send it back to them? Or are you talking about a different client?

Comment: Yes exactly, like i'm uploading it from my mobile phone it should besend to my computer for example

Comment: If you're talking about sending uploaded files to a _specific_ client (like your laptop or something), you might want to consider just using emails. if you _really_ want to do [push notifications to a client](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-thomson-webpush-protocol-00), prepare for a deep rabbit-hole. [web-push-php](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php) and [PHP-Push-WebSocket](https://github.com/srchea/PHP-Push-WebSocket) are good places to start.

Comment: It might be simpler for the computer to run a cron job that periodically downloads files.

Comment: If its just the one computer, you can run the server on that computer and upload files to it and save them to a directory without a lot of hassle... but need to be secure

Comment: And in case there a multiple clients? I want the server to "dispense" the file to the appropriate clients. Is it not possible to do it this way, or is a complete different way better?

Comment: @Ice76 forgot to mention that it is a webserver!

Comment: @JacobBalb this is going to be very difficult to do since it opens up a lot of security issues. Pushing files onto a client can be taken advantage of. It can be done, but very difficult.

Comment: @Ice76 Security neglects can be left out, it is just about the principle for now. Is there a way to do it better than this, maybe even an easier one like other serverstructures?

Comment: @JacobBalb other server structures would be a networking thing. You can look into creating a shared file server that clients have access to. Why do you need to push to the client?

Comment: @Ice76 I don't really need to push it, but I thought it is less extensive if it will send the data to the client when it gets a file, than the client checking for files permanently, but it might be a wrong way of thinking.

Comment: Well, you can push or send a file to any client using php, but only up to some point. First you have to know how you want to do this. How do you want to receive the file? Do you intend to use FTP or any other Protocol to copy it there? Maybe over local network? How do you secure your connection? What happens if the client is not responding? Before you start, you will have to figure out, how you want to copy the files aside from PHP. What options do you have to connect your Server to the Clients? After that you can plan the actual code to do this.

Comment: @JacobBalb PHP is not the best solution for persistent connections/data transfer, especially with many clients. Its possible, but there are better options out there for that. As far as pushing data to a client over HTTP, not common and I think there might be a better solution to your problem. I am not sure why you need to do this, either, so not much I can help with recommendations

Comment: @Ice76 so would it be better to use any other languages except script languages?